Microsoft Azure Dev Box - Shared Instance
Looking to do an initial PoC of MS Azure Dev Box, and looking to keep it very small at first.
Is it possible to share INSTANCES of Dev Boxes across users?
This is intended to reduce the up front time to setup and the monthly cost per instance.  We only for now need these boxes for basic testing and 2 users will not be using it at the same time.

No.  You can not share instances of a DevBox.  You can share images of a dev box that would make getting up to speed quicker.
We recently ran into a similar issue where we wanted to create a VM and then allow one person to use it at the time and after creating the VM realized i couldn't share it :( '
See the associated link for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1336888/shared-devbox

